# After Jenkins is installed in Vagrant, cannot connect from browser

Tags: shell, ubuntu, jenkins, continuous-integration, vagrant

I'm trying to install Jenkins on Vagrant for my development environment.

I choose Ubuntu http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/precise/current/precise-server-cloudimg-vagrant-amd64-disk1.box for my box. And this is the shell that I use to provision my box up. Everything went ok, but when I tried accessing the box from port 80 or even :8080 it's just not responding. The browsing just kept spinning. Not sure what I did wrong here.

Here's my script.

```
sudo apt-get update

echo "APT::Cache-Limit "100000000";" >> /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/70debconf

wget -q -O - http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian/jenkins-ci.org.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo deb http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/debian binary/ > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jenkins.list'

sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install jenkins

sudo apt-get -y --force-yes install apache2
sudo a2enmod proxy
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
sudo a2enmod vhost_alias
sudo a2dissite default

echo '
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName ci.company.com
        ServerAlias ci
        ProxyRequests Off
        
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        
        ProxyPreserveHost on
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
' >> /etc/apache2/sites-available/jenkins

sudo a2ensite jenkins
sudo sh -c 'echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/conf.d/name' && sudo service apache2 restart
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Also I `vagrant ssh` and run

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080'
```

and it returned the Jenkins page, so I think Jenkins is up and running properly. I just couldn't access it from outside.

Here's my Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "install-jenkins.sh"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2024"]
  end

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu64"

  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing "localhost:8080" will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 8080
end
```

Comment: Standard question: is there some kind of firewall involved?

Comment: But from my understanding empty ubuntu doesn't have any firewall up? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Maybe, I don't know the interna of your specific box - is your Jenkins listening on port 80 in your VM, I have some vague idea that it may listen on port 8080 by default?

Comment: I install apache2 to port forward that to 8080. As you can see that I setup that in my script. I also tried sudo ufw disable to disable everything. But it still didn't work.

Comment: Try a portforwarding from 8080 to 8080 to temporarily circumvent apache2 so if this works it may in error in the apache2 conf.

Comment: Just tried that and it's still not working. :-(

Comment: I made this work by providing an IP to the Vagrant box like this: `config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.33.10"`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, that really works. Please answer it and I'll accept the answer. :-).

Comment: Jepp that seems to be a suitable workaround but port forwarding should work nevertheless since I'm using it heavily :-) Also please use something like 10.x.y.z as your internal IPs because 33.33.33.10 is a valid internet address and you won't be able to reach it (or the whole 33.33.33.x) anymore

Comment: Absolutely correct. The IP address was just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this work by providing an IP to the Vagrant box like this:

```
config.vm.network :hostonly, "33.33.33.10"
```

Comment: can you explain ? because it's not working for me, plus i assume its not hostonly but private network